# Do lightning nodes charge fees for their own channels?

Tags: lightning-routing, lightning-fees

My node has a bunch of channels. If I want to make payment, then by definition it will find a route that goes through one or more of my own channels. Are the current lightning implementations smart enough not to charge a fee for that?

In a sense it doesn't matter because the fee goes to the node operator, which is me. But from a bookkeeping point of view it does matter if you're keeping track of transactions *including* fees.

Conversely it matters if you're trying to find out how much you made from routing (for others).

Finally, I assume it makes a slight difference in the maximum payment you can make.

E.g. in CLN's `listpays` result there's `amount_msat`, the invoice amount, and `amount_sent_msat`, the amount sent. It's documentation doesn't mention if this includes fees in our own channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightning nodes charge a fee when they *forward* a multi-hop payment based on the fee announcement of the outbound channel.

E.g. if you are originating the payment, and your route is via Alice and Bob to the recipient `S ⇒ A ⇒ B ⇒ R`, Alice will collect a fee for sending to Bob based on the announced fees for her channel with Bob, and Bob will collect a fee for sending to the recipient based on the announced fees for the Bob-Recipient channel.

If you send a multipath payment, the same principle holds true: your own node does not charge a fee for the first hops.
As the recipient does not forward the payment, your node also does not charge a fee when you receive a payment.

So, the only scenario in which your own node would charge a fee would be if you operate multiple nodes and a multi-hop payment from one of your nodes is routed through the other.

Comment: That makes sense. Is this mentioned in the spec? Or just a convention? A the level of transactions that are created, there's no difference between S => A and A => B? Or is there?

Comment: At the level of the transactions there is no difference, otherwise the first hop would be able to tell that the sender is the sender. But the payment is sender-routed and the sender knows that it’s their own payment, so why should it charge a fee of itself?

Comment: Just checked with Core Lightning v24.02.1 - when paying an invoice with a destination that I have a direct channel with, the `amount_msat` and `amount_sent_msat` fields are the same. When the payments goes via another node first, the amounts are different. The channel has a `fee-per-satoshi` value set. I haven't tested if other clients do this too, though it seems plausible.